# Browser issue in Ctrl-R

Tags: browser

I have am facing browser issue - in an application, when I press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> key in IE the page refreshes and control values also reset, but when I press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> in Firefox the page refreshes but control values are not not reset.

Now I want to reset the control values also on <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>R</kbd> instead of using some other keys.  How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a feature of Firefox, not an inconsistency in your website. It also happens to be one that a lot of users have a habit of getting upset about if you try to mess with, as no doubt it's saved them a few times when they accidentally refresh a page.

Please don't try to disable this, think of your users.