# "location.reload()" loses POST/SESSION data? (F5 / Ctrl+R keeps data?)

Tags: javascript, session, browser-refresh

I want to create a button to reload a page without losing `$_POST` data and `$_SESSION`.
On the web, I found this piece of code:

```
onclick="document.location.reload();"
```

And here is the code of my button:

```
<a class="button" href="" style="font-size: 0.7em; padding: 5px 10px;" onclick="document.location.reload();">Recharger la page</a>
```

**But when I click on the button, I lose `$_POST` data and `$_SESSION`.**

If I try with the keyboard command *Ctrl+R* (Chrome) or *F5* (Firefox, IE9), the browser is showing an alert to notify me that I'm again trying to submit form. If I accept, it works.

How can I reproduce this kind of browser-refresh with a JavaScript command? Or is the code of my button wrong?

Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 9):

Try using

```
location.reload(true);
```

This will perform a "hard" refresh, not just rebuilding the DOM but also re-retrieving any resource from the server.

[You can read more at the Mozilla Developer wiki.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.location#section_6)

Apparently, `location.reload()` is the equivalent of `F5` in scripting, whilst `Ctrl+F5` / `Ctrl+R` can be simulated using `location.reload(true)`.

Also, as ThiefMaster mentioned, you're missing `;return false` at the end of your `onclick` statement, or you should set the `href` to `javascript:void 0`<sup>*</sup> to prevent the browser from following the link.

<sub>*Or any other piece of JavaScript that returns `undefined`</sub>

Comment: When I use location.reload(true), browser is giving the alert to notify that I'm again trying to submit form. If I accept, it doesn't work. Is it due to the href=""?

Comment: That's because the browser will reload using exactly the same parameters and request method as it used when it loaded the page for the first time. If you don't want to repeat this, you could better first store the data in $_SESSION and then do a `header("303 See Other")` and a `header("Location: $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']")` to reload the page with a GET request.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but ThiefMaster gave me the solution :)

Comment: `location.reload(true)` doesn't POST anything, GET request is used instead.

Answer (score 2):

This should happen in any case as long as you are on the same location you POSTed to. However, it's common to redirect after a POST request to avoid exactly what you are trying to do.

The reason why your code doesn't work is the fact that `href=""` will cause a GET request to the current URL. Use `href="#"` to prevent it from loading a "new" page or add `return false;` at the end of your `onclick="..."` code.

Comment: When in press F5, in Firefox for instance, It works fine. I just want to find a way to do that with a javascript button ?

Comment: `location.reload()` should do the job as you can see on http://jsfiddle.net/ThiefMaster/thTyD/ (note that you must click "Run" first so the output pane was actually loaded via POST).

Comment: But my code above doesn't work… onclick="document.location.reload();". Is it due to the href=""?

Comment: Yes, you need to use `href="#"` or `return false;` at the end of your onclick.

Comment: `href="#"` always jumps to the top of the page. [Try this link for instance.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10861176/location-reload-loses-post-session-data-f5-ctrlr-keeps-data/#). That's really annoying. For this reason, I recommend using `javascript:void 0` (or any JavaScript that returns `undefined`) instead.

Answer (score 0):

The `Ctrl + R` refreshes the page *and* clears your cache. And I guess you're using Internet Explorer? Some other browsers behave like this when you hit `Ctrl + F5`, but not with `Ctrl + R`

Sources:
https://superuser.com/questions/205279/ctrlf5-vs-ctrlr-on-browsers
[Browser issue in Ctrl-R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5879308/browser-issue-in-ctrl-r)

Comment: I usually work in FF but I'm on a project wich demands to be cross-browsers :)